# What bit to use to cut a hole in quartz counter top?

Tags: kitchen-counters

What bit should I use to cut a hole to put in quartz counter top. I got a Glass ceramic tile bit and was wondering if that would work

Comment: How large a hole? My instincts say diamond-grit holesaw, carbide at the very least, and quite possibly a pressure-drilling rig of some sort... but I may be overkilling the problem. Also, is this real quartz or "cultured stone"?

Comment: a inch hole for a faucet. Its real quartz

Answer (score 2):

You will cut this as it is granite and use a diamond tip hole bit (see [example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CY3U7QI) that I have used).  Not an endorsement because I cut a hole in granite 3-4 times a year but they worked fine for me.

Quartz is a little easier to cut than granite but I would still go diamond.  Also make sure you have someone pouring water on the scene, take you time, put little to no pressure on the bit after it starts, and if things are going too slow reverse and pull the bit out and try again (let it cool and clear out debris).

Comment: Sanity check: If it's a hole bit, you generally shouldn't have to reverse to pull it out, since there aren't flutes to clear...?

Comment: @keshlam - If you are "stuck" it helps also it is generally easier.  But no you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a powerdrill and 21 dollar diamond hole saw from HD.  Is your hole for a faucet? For a standard faucet hole, you need a 1 3/8" diamond hole saw. search for "Thrifty Tani" on youtube. I have a video on how I did it. He'res a link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFWvVzlGF4Y&t=5s